# Audacity: Increase audio volume in audacity software

Tags: mp3, volume, audacity

How can I increase audio volume of a mp3 file in audacity?

I need to cut a part of mp3 song to make a ringtone. But as I save it in by mobile, the volume is too low for this particular file. Is there a way to increase volume of mp3 file in audacity *without distorting quality*?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Effect>Amplify and mess with it (press preview) until it sounds right. If the waveforms look too big, undo it and try again. Hope this helps :)

I don't think this will add distortion but if it does, I can reach back in my head and dig out the other way of raising the volume.

Comment: Digital amplification like this won't add any distortion until it hits the format's maximum amplitude. Then it'll hard-clip horribly :)

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought but sometimes I do things that end up all weird.

Comment: Audacity will automatically calculate the amplification needed to bring the volume up to 0dB so you shouldn't have to mess around with the values at all, do keep in mind that this only works for one sound file at a time though. You cannot batch-amplify using this process.

Answer (score -2):

equalisation works a lot better than amp, however even it cannot inc the sound of all mp3 perfectly, sometimes distortion does creep in[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually show anything about how to increase the volume, it just shows how to get to the Equalizer and is left as an exercise to the user to figure out how that would be helpful.  (Which I can't figure out even with 15 years of sound experience, particularly since EQs are best done subtractively.)

Answer (score -2):

First normalize to -1dB which is the default.  Use function normalize.
Then lower it about 18 with amplify. Again that is in function amplify.
Next  compress it 2.5x1  ratio in function compress.
Then check that the make up gain brings you to -1dB else normalize again.

Comment: See my comment on https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/46834/9601 Don't do this.

Comment: Sorry but that works as stated. You might need to use more or less compression  but 2.5x1 is a good start.